# How do I loop through a file with awk

Tags: linux, ksh

I am using this command `sed -e '/^*/d' $WORKFILE | awk -f test.awk  >> $OUTPUTFILE`
in a ksh script to take a file of 274567 lines like this

```
*
*
*
*
*
 syopsf00
         a0000096
                 782            1
         CAStmtInv
 syopsf00
         a0000096
                 782            1
         USStmtInv
 syopsf00
         a0000096
                 606            1
         CAStmtInv
 syopsf00
         a0000096
                 606            1
         USStmtInv
 syopsf00
         a0000096
               23472            4
         AO
 syopsf00
         a0000096
               23472            4
         Dealer
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
```

and produce a file with lines like this

```
syopsf00 a0000096 782 1 CAStmtInv
syopsf00 a0000096 782 1 USStmtInv
syopsf00 a0000096 606 1 CAStmtInv
syopsf00 a0000096 606 1 USStmtInv
```

but all I get is this

```
syopsf00 a0000096 782 1 CAStmtInv
```

this is what the awk script  (test.awk) looks like

```
BEGIN {
         RS="\n\n";
         FS=" ";

}
END {
         print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5;
}
```

Comment: Your RS is two consecutive newlines, which I don't see at all in your file contents. And your printing only once, at the end of input, so only values of the last record will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

While (given your input) it's not quite clear what you're trying to do in full the problem with the output is that only the last line fed into awk will ever be printed because of the fact that you put the print in the END statement.

It should look like this:

```
BEGIN { 
  RS="\n\n"; FS=" ";
}
{ 
  print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5; 
}
```

Note: the indentation is just my personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

I hope sole `awk` will be enough

```
awk '
     /syopsf00/{print ""}
     !/^[*]/{printf "%s",$0}
     END{print ""}
    ' $WORKFILE >> $OUTPUTFILE
```

Or if you wants to strip multi-spaces and use awk-scriptfile:

```
awk -f test.awk "$WORKFILE" >> "$OUTPUTFILE"
```

where `test.awk` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
/syopsf00/{print ""}
!/^[*]/{printf ("%s",$1" "$2" "}
END{print ""}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure `sed` one-liner:

```
sed ':X;N;s/*//;$!bX;s/\n  /\t/g;:Y;s/\n\n//g;tY' $WORKFILE
```

It may look quite complicated at first but basically it removes all `*`, then removes all newlines followed by two spaces (`'\n  '`) and lastly removes double newlines `\n\n` to clean up. Most probably this expresion can be simplified.

I included tab `\t` instead of spaces as field separator to align columns better, the output is

```
 syopsf00          a0000096                782            1        CAStmtInv
 syopsf00          a0000096                782            1        USStmtInv
 syopsf00          a0000096                606            1        CAStmtInv
 syopsf00          a0000096                606            1        USStmtInv
 syopsf00          a0000096              23472            4        AO
 syopsf00          a0000096              23472            4        Dealer
```